# Moment.js: Not include all timezones in TZInfo::Timezone.all

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, momentjs

While creating the user, we take timezone as user-input from list by TZInfo::Timezone.all.
I have to show date_time columns in current-user's timezone in grid-list.

For this, I have used moment-timezone.js to convert date_time field value to correct timezone and format.

The problem is for time-zones which are present in TZInfo::Timezone.all list and not in moment-timezone-data.js gives JavaScript error.

I want to use client-side conversion not want to modify column value at server side.

Is there any solution?